# COMET no JS framework links/tutorials?

Tags: comet

Are there any sites that has a tutorial about COMET without the use of any javascript framework? I want to see the core codes of COMET and learn how it works.

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: So i guess there is no tutorial? I searched thoroughly in google but I can't find any COMET no js framework tutorial :(

Answer (score 3):

Without the use of a javascript framework, you're dead in the water (unless you want to use Flash/Silverlight). Javascript is an integral part of how Comet works.

If you want to play with some Comet tutorials, you can check out the ones we've written for [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials). You can take a look at the underlying javascript as well; tack ?debug=1 on the end of the script tag to view the uncompressed version.

Comment: So you're trying to say that COMET depends to a Javascript framework and will not work alone? Thanks for the link. I will check that :)

Comment: Essentially, yes; you need both a comet *server* and a comet *client*. You *can* use another client (such as Silverlight/Flash/Thick clients/etc), but you'll always need *something* to communicate with the server. JavaScript is the most common because it's supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can follow to the these urls for COMET.**

```
http://ape-project.org/
http://www.xajax-project.org/en/download/
http://www.xajax-project.org/developer/q_no/Comet/comet.php
```